# Get files from web service

Tags: android, json

I have a URL(http://xxx.xxx/api/getFiles) which is returning a JSON response. According to the developer of the API, this link also return files (images, pdf, word, excel, video, etc) that we're going to download to our Android device.

This link returns a file path (e.g. "/File Folder/") and file name (e.g. "Penguins.jpg") that will be used to link the file to the web server but I don't have an idea how to do it.

Are there ways to download it using this API?

JSON response:

```
{ 
   "status":"success",
   "count":1,
   "files":[ 
      { 
         "file_code":"2",
         "file_name":"Penguins.jpg",
         "file_type":".jpg",
         "file_path”:”\/File Folder\/“
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This is confusing. How can a 'get' service send you a local link to get files? As according to the question, that's what I'm getting.

Comment: You haven't shown us the result you get when you hit `http://xxx.xxx/api/getFiles`. It's hard to answer the question this way.

Comment: I'm getting this response everytime I call this API. But, I don't know how to download this files.

{ 
   "status":"success",
   "count":1,
   "files":[ 
      { 
         "file_code":"2",
         "file_name":"Penguins.jpg",
         "file_type":".jpg",
         "file_path”:”\/File Folder\/“
      }
   ]
}

Comment: **1.** such information should be added/updated in your question with formatting/code ticks. **2.** You should take this JSON to the server-end developer and ask him how you can get download URLs from this. **3.** Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Last time, I was able to download a file using a URL (e.g. http://xxx.xxx/files/Penguins.jpg) but they said I'm hot linking to the web server.

Answer (score 1):

To download file from url following peice of code can help you:
This code will create connection with url server and download it to specified path:

```
        int downloadedSize = 0;
        int totalSize = 0;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("download file url");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //connect
            urlConnection.connect();

            //set the path where we want to save the file
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //create a new file, to save the downloaded file
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot, "DownloadFileNameWithExtension"); // like test.png

            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
            totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();


            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;

            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            }
            //close the output stream when complete //
            fileOutput.close();

        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Don't forget to add Internet permission in your manifest:D